# Deploying Grails applications in Google AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine, grails, grails-plugin, cloud-hosting

Hi i am a developer that has been using Grails framework for 2 years.

Currently the company i work for is pushing for Google App Engine development. We are a very large retailer and already have ties with google products.

I still do not know much about Google App Engine development. 
From what i understand it seems that you have to develop with their Java SDK. 
Meaning your applications must be developed specifically for their hosting platform.
I am not about to give up Grails, so am hesitant.

So questions:

1. I would like to know if anyone has experance with trying to integrate Grails applications into Google AppEngine ?
2. Is it possible to simply push a Grails project packaged as a war into Google AppEngine?
3. I found this [Grails AppEngine plug-in](http://www.grails.org/plugin/app-engine). But then i don't want my projects to depend on a plugin. Anyone used it?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12430706/grails-on-google-app-engine-is-it-dead

Answer (score 1):

This is well covered in a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12430706/grails-on-google-app-engine-is-it-dead).

What it boils down to is that GAE places certain restrictions on what you can do with a Java application, so yes you are correct that you have to develop your application specifically for their platform. This is not a bad thing per se; Google's platform is designed for scalability so some constraints are necessary.

If you are really tied to Google's cloud platform, you might consider deploying Grails on Google [Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/products/compute-engine/), which is a more traditional virtual Linux server environment.