# Setup Grails application in Google AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine, grails, groovy, grails-plugin

I created grails application and tried to setup the application in google app engine.

I got error like this

```
../plugins/app-engine-0.8.10/src/groovy/org/grails/appengine/Log4jConfigListener.groovy: 32: unable to resolve class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.logging.Log4jConfig
 @ line 32, column 1.
   import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.logging.Log4jConfig;
   ^

../plugins/app-engine-0.8.10/src/groovy/org/grails/appengine/Log4jConfigListener.groovy: 83: unable to resolve class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.logging.Log4jConfig 
 @ line 83, column 1.
   class AppEngineLog4jConfig extends org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.logging.Log4jConfig{
   ^
```

Then i searched, i found some info that "Grails 2.0 or later version not supports app engine  plugin", you can see [Here](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.groovy.grails.user/121976).

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The App Engine plugin has not been updated for Grails 2.x. Please refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12430706/grails-on-google-app-engine-is-it-dead) for more information.

Comment: Yes, as described in the answer to the other question.

Comment: More than Gaelyk documentation, where can i get more info about how to work with Gaelyk from the base.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "work with Gaelyk from the base"?

Comment: I am sorry but I am not fully understanding your question. Are you asking about how to build Gaelyk from the source code base? If that's the case I don't think there's too much information out there. A good place to start is to pull down the sources from GitHub and build the distribution.

Comment: i am finding difficult know " how to create project using Gaelyk", i saw documentation but, difficult to understand.

Comment: can i get any Gaelyk project link at GitHub or any other Gaelyk guide.

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding your questions. I assume you are asking about a sample project built with Gaelyk? Maybe a tutorial of how to [build a simple CRUD app](http://globalgateway.wordpress.com/2010/10/21/simple-crud-with-gaelyk/) helps.